# Telegram bot API limitations

Tags: python, bots, telegram

If you open telegram bot FAQ you can see 1 message per second inside particular chat, 30 messages per second inside group chat and less than 20 messages per minute inside group chat.

I have simple telegram bot with simple rate limiter:

1. it doesn't use group chats;
2. it sends only 1 message per second inside particular chat;
3. it sends less than 20 messages per minute inside particular chat;

But i always receive 429 error:

```
"error_code":429,"description":"Too Many Requests: retry after 236"
```

I confused since i don't violate telegram limitations. Please, help me to find problem.

Source code [here](https://github.com/Ksenishka/Bot-Telegram), bot uses [this](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) library for interaction with telegram in poll mode. Steps to reproduce:

```
1) python3 bot.py;
2) /start in bot;
3) click "Спектакли";
4) click very fast on "Трагикомедии" or "Драма";
```

Comment: This will be useful:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329364/what-are-telegram-client-messaging-limits/49399458#49399458](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329364/what-are-telegram-client-messaging-limits/49399458#49399458)

Comment: I got this message if I break the 2nd rule - sends more than ~ 10 messages within 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Your msg_count seems is tracking sended messages for each private chat. But it should be global, beacuse its seems that your current code allows your bot to send a few messages per second to unlimited users. So it would probably exceed the limit.

> If you're sending bulk notifications to multiple users, the API will
>   not allow more than 30 messages per second or so. Consider spreading
>   out notifications over large intervals of 8—12 hours for best results.
>   [Telegram Bots FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this)

Comment: Yes, you are right, but i got this error on particular one client (one chat_id). So first i wanna understand why it happens.