# What are Telegram Client Messaging limits?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

From [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq) I know that Telegram limits BOT messages like this:

**> 1msg/second per chat**

**> 30msg/second different chats**

Happens that I'am not using the [python-telegram-bot API](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot), I'am using a normal client through [telethon's library](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon). I'am getting Flood\Spam error from Telegram when trying to send messages in that cadence. BTW, I'am using [delayQueue Class](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/ext/messagequeue.py) to control the messages limits like this:

```
dqueue = DelayQueue(burst_limit=29, time_limit_ms=1014)
dqueue(client.send_message,inputPeerUser,msg)
```

Already asked directly to telegram's support, but got no answer. Does someone know what are the limits to normal clients?

Comment: whats the flood error?

Comment: is the error I get when telegram blocks me because of SPAM. Flood\spam

Comment: You need to mention exact error message with stacklog

Comment: sorry, but, why would this be important? The error is from telethon.errors.rpc_error_list PeerFloodError (too much messages sent) I can't reproduce that  because I would block my account for more days. The thing is, I'am getting blocked by Telegram because of SPAM, just need to know the messaging limits in order to respect that and don't get blocked.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a limit of 30 msg/sec.

Also,a bot can use the API requests for a limited no. of times

I get this error when I usually test the bot.During testing,there would be a lot of scenarios to test.So,I would be sending a huge amount of requests.

I get an error like this, `{error_code:429,description:Too many requests try after (some_time)}`
Idk the exact limit.

**To avoid this:**
You should not flood the telegram server with requests

Comment: So for exemple If I send 29 messages to 29 different people per second, I wont get blocked?

Comment: But there is also a limit for messages sent within a day (or something  larger than a second)

Comment: know where those limits are?

Comment: There isn't any mention of that in the official site itself